# Swimming on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, swimming

Is it permitted to go swimming on Shabbos?

Comment: Why might you think it is or isnt'?

Answer (score 11):

The original statement of prohibition as brought in the Gemarah Maseches Shabbos against swimming on Shabbos has to do with concern that one may perform "Gibul" - mushing the dirt at the side of the body of water into mud which would be a *toldah* of *lash*, kneading. As Yirmiyahu said there is also the concern of making a raft. Therefore in an outdoor pool most poskim do not permit it, (although R' Leizer Silver seemingly did. See  http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2007_01_01_archive.html). Indoor pools are permitted by a minority although most major poskim do not recommend it. Rav Moshe Feinstein writes that the *minhag* is that one should not immerse even in cold water on Shabbos unless it is for a *mitzvah*. (Igroth Moshe, Even Haezer 2,13.) There is also the concern of wringing out one's hair. There are those who say that going into the pool with a bathing suit on is laundering. Also see http://www.dafyomi.co.il/shabbos/insites/sh-dt-041.htm .

Comment: Igros Moshe writes the swimming in a swimming pool is mutar on Shabbos. He then notes that in America, the minhag is not to. But he is quite clear that it is allowed, according to the law. And it seems to me that in many communities today in America, the custom has changed people do swim.

Comment: @Curiouser--1. He says it is permitted when it is in an area it is permitted to carry and that even there it is forbidden to do so while wearing a bathing suit. 2.  The minhag is NOT discussing "American" practice but Ashkenazi practice not to bathe, which is the authoritative Ashkenazi minhag.

Comment: This answer could really use some sources for its claims.

Comment: Any Sephardi authority discuss this?

Answer (score 6):

Mishneh Torah [*Hilkhoth Shabath* 23:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.23.5) says:

> אֵין שָׁטִין עַל פְּנֵי הַמַּיִם גְּזֵרָה שֶׁמָּא יְתַקֵּן חָבִית שֶׁל שַׁיָּטִין. בְּרֵכָה שֶׁבֶּחָצֵר מֻתָּר לָשׁוּט בְּתוֹכָהּ שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָּא לַעֲשׂוֹת חָבִית שֶׁל שַׁיָּטִין וְהוּא שֶׁיִּהְיֶה לָהּ שָׂפָה מֻקֶּפֶת שֶׁלֹּא יֵעָקֵר מִמֶּנָּה הַמַּיִם. כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּהְיֶה הֶכֵּר וְהֶפְרֵשׁ בֵּינָהּ וּבֵין הַיָּם:‏

Translation:

> We do not swim in [open, natural bodies of] water [on *Shabbat*]. This is a rabbinic decree lest one come to construct a barrel of reeds [i.e. for a flotation device]. A [man-made] pool inside of a courtyard [i.e. enclosed with an *eruv*] is permissible to swim in as long as it has a lip surrounding it so that the water cannot run out of it [onto the ground around it], and in this way there will be a definite distinction between it and the sea.

So we see that it **is** indeed permissible to swim on *Shabath*, provided that it is in a pool, with a rim, within a valid *`eruv.*

[See also *`Arokh HaShulhan*, *Hilkhoth Shabath*, *siman* 339, *se'iph* 4 for a fuller explanation of the halakhic difference between swimming in a river or lake and swimming in a pool.]

Now, beside swimming itself there are several other issues raised by the occasion of swimming that have halakhic concerns, both regarding *hilkhoth Shabath* and otherwise:

1. ***Swimming attire*** - In ancient times, swimming was done without a bathing suit. In other words, the one swimming would do so while nude. Therefore, this *halakha* is likely dealing with such a scenario. Given the prohibition on *kibus* (laundering), how can one wear an article of clothing while in the water, isn't this *kibus*?
2. ***Wet hair*** - We know that it is prohibited to wring out things on *Shabath* (*s'hitta* as a derivative of *disha*), so wouldn't wringing out wet hair fall under this category?
3. ***Tzeni`uth*** (modesty) - Is mixed bathing/swimming permissible? Can one go to a public pool on *Shabath*?
4. ***Heating water*** - Most pools are heated and heating water is forbidden on *Shabath* so is it prohibited to swim in a modern "heated" pool on *Shabath*?

The answers to these questions are a bit complex in their explanation, but I will attempt to answer them concisely.

A. There are many issues with regard to *kibus* that could be discussed, but essentially the question is whether one can get clothing wet and for what purpose. A clean suit worn into clean water is not considered *kibus* since it essentially effects nothing. As for drying, the second part of *kibus*, since people do not seek to immediately dry their suits but instead remove them while still wet, there is no issue there either. As for wringing out a bathing suit, as long as it is made of synthetic materials (such as polyester or nylon) there is absolutely no issue since we have a principle of "*ein disha ela b'gidule qarqa`* - there is no concern for [the *melakha* of] *disha* except with articles made of [plant] materials that grow from the ground" (cf. b.*Shabath* 75a et al). Therefore, there is no prohibition of squeezing synthetic materials (more on this in the next section). And even if one were to wear cotton while swimming, it would be fine as long as one does not wring them out or squeeze them - provided they are clean and the water is clean.

B. Pursuant to the previous section, wringing out wet hair also does not present a halakhic issue. It states explicitly in *Mishne Tora* (*Hilkhoth Shabath* 9:11) that there is no prohibition of "squeezing" or "wringing" (*s'hitta*) with regard to hair or leather. There are those who maintain that the Rambam holds here that there is no *isur* of *s'hitta* **min ha-Tora**, but a *mi-divrehem* prohibition still applies, however this is incorrect as is explained by the *pirush* of Rav Yosef Qafih z"l (there, #32). The hair or beard may be squeezed and wrung out on *Shabath* without any concern at all.

C. Mixed swimming is not permissible. There are those who are liberal who will certainly argue on this, but it is nevertheless not permitted for modesty reasons. The sources for this are abundant and there is no need to list them here. However, it appears *l`aniyuth da'ati* that immediate family swimming together while **clothed** (i.e. not in underwear, bikinis, etc.) is perfectly fine. This may be derived from the laws permitting even *qiruv basar* while sleeping between nuclear family members in the same bed of the opposite gender. Once the child has shame, clothing or a blanket to separate between skin and skin is required. Swimming together while clothed in a private pool (without other people) should be fine, and the small children who are still toddlers unaware of their own bodies could swim in any bathing suit or even without clothing. [See MT *Hilkhoth Isure Bi'a* 21:6-7 et al].

D. The prohibition to heat water on *Shabath* is only in regard to the temperature of *yadh soledeth bo* (around 110 F). Thus, a slightly-warmed pool is not an issue. [See *`Arokh HaShulhan*, *Hilkhoth Shabath*, *siman* 326 , *se'if* 3]

In closing, there are those who claim that swimming is not in the "spirit" of *Shabath*. However, we must ask ourselves what determines this "spirit." It seems that *Hazal* felt that the "spirit" of *Shabath* was to be determined by the *halakha* - i.e. through prohibiting *melakha*, not discussing *melakhoth*, nor doing things that may lead to *halakhoth*. Swimming (within the guidelines set by Hazal) does not fit any of those descriptions. Instead, it seems that taking a permissible "dip" on the Seventh Day may actually fall into the category of *`onegh Shabath* (this view is also expressed by Rav Yisshaq Abadi shlit"a, as can be found on his website kashrut.org).

A helpful *teshuva* by Rav Rasson `Arusi *shlit"a* on this subject - containing much of what has been explained here - may be found [**here**](http://net-sah.org/faq/18779).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27494/discussion-on-answer-by-maimonist-swimming-on-shabbos).

Comment: @Double AA - What is this? Leave my answers alone, please. If they are "off topic" then they will be voted down. Removing contextual statements does damage to my answer. Being this was written close to a year ago, I assume you chose to do this now for some other motivation. Please explain to me why you felt it necessary to do this.

Comment: Are you going to be trotting out all the answers on Mi Yodeya and eliminating content you deem "off topic"?

Comment: @Maimonist My job, actually, is to trot around Mi Yodeya and eliminate content I deem [based on community developed guidelines] is "off topic", among other things. I've been doing so for years and plan to continue doing so.

Comment: The jab at Charedim at the end was obviously unnecessary and probably falls afoul of our "be nice" policy. Indeed all the discussion in the beginning about the social function of various rulings about swimming is also just your social commentary where you impugn other's intentions, not an answer to the question. Finally the bit about forbidding the permitted is as irrelevant to this post as accusations of Bal Tosif are to rabbinic commandments. At best it belongs in a separate question.

Comment: Additionally, adding source to support your claim that "it seems that Hazal felt that the 'spirit' of Shabath was to be determined by the halakha - i.e. through prohibiting melakha, not discussing melakhoth, nor doing things that may lead to halakhoth" would improve your conclusion. I for one don't think it seems that way at all from Chazal. Even so, +1 on what you do have here which outlines some of the major issues with some relevant sources.

Comment: Hair does absorb water, so how is it not schita?

Comment: @Emet v'Shalom - Read the Rambam and the sources I cited. It is explicit that hair and leather do not absorb halakhically. Also, the Gemara explains, "*ein dishah ela be-gidulei qarqa*" which means that s'hitah is only an issue with materials that grow from the ground - excluding animal or synthetic materials, such as leather, wool, or nylon. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom Hair doesn't absorb water. What are you talking about? Is hair that porous? Wet hair means water is adhering to the outside of the hair, not being absorbed.

Answer (score 3):

Swimming is prohibited (in open bodies of water) out of concern that one might construct a [makeshift] raft.

Indeed, the prohibition against swimming is one of the reasons, as I recall, for the Ashkenazi practice not to bathe even in cold water on Shabbos (which itself precludes swimming in those situations where the prohibition isn't otherwise applicable). The prohibition against laundering prohibits entering the water while wearing clothes.

Shabbos 40b
Misnhen Torah: Shabbos 23:5
Shulchan Aruch: Orach Chaim 339:2
[Igros Moshe Even HaEzer 2:13](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1238/899)
Shemiras Shabbos K'Hilchasa 14:12

Comment: But if you look in the shulchan aruch there is an exception of if the pool has a lip (ledge that will hold the water from splashing out) of it is in a vessel then it is permitted